# MySQL timeout with azure data factory copy

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network

I am using azure data factory to copy data from MySQL server as source. The data is big in size. When I setup the pipeline and execute it:

```
MySQL: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I think this can be solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475867/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-timeout-expired). How can I add this configuration to my data factory pipeline using MySQL as source?

**Update**: I am  using a normal script to copy data from on-premise MySQL to SQL data warehouse. The MySQL query is simple select: `select * from mytable;`
Complete Error:

> Copy activity encountered a user error at Source side:
>   GatewayNodeName=MYGATEWAY,ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedMashupOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message='Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException,Message=MySQL:
>   Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not
>   responding.,Source=Microsoft.MashupEngine,',Source=,'.

Comment: Can you confirm that it's about default time out configuration? The answer you post is just using MySQL Connector, it's different from data factory  on Azure.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that the query to fetch data takes too much time. Might even take more than hour. I am getting above error in the pipeline around 10 minutes into execution.

Comment: It might be MYSQL timeout issue. Post `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout%";` output

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this issue is about default time out  configuration ,you can add these scripts in `"activities"` in  your pipeline settings to set **timeout** to 1 hour:

```
"Policy": {
       "concurrency": 1,
       "timeout": "01:00:00"
 }
```

----------Update----------

the whole JSON of pipeline configuration like this:

```
{
     "name": "ADFTutorialPipelineOnPrem",
     "properties": {
     "description": "This pipeline has one Copy activity that copies data from an on-prem SQL to Azure blob",
     "activities": [
       {
         "name": "CopyFromSQLtoBlob",
         "description": "Copy data from on-prem SQL server to blob",
         "type": "Copy",
         "inputs": [
           {
             "name": "EmpOnPremSQLTable"
           }
         ],
         "outputs": [
           {
             "name": "OutputBlobTable"
           }
         ],
         "typeProperties": {
           "source": {
             "type": "SqlSource",
             "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from emp"
           },
           "sink": {
             "type": "BlobSink"
           }
         },
         "Policy": {
           "concurrency": 1,
           "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
           "style": "StartOfInterval",
           "retry": 0,
           "timeout": "01:00:00"
         }
       }
     ],
     "start": "2016-07-05T00:00:00Z",
     "end": "2016-07-06T00:00:00Z",
     "isPaused": false
   }
 }
```

This following sample assumes you have created a table “MyTable” in MySQL and it contains a column called “timestampcolumn” for time series data.Setting “external”: ”true” informs the Data Factory service that the table is external to the data factory and is not produced by an activity in the data factory.:

```
{
        "name": "MySqlDataSet",
        "properties": {
            "published": false,
            "type": "RelationalTable",
            "linkedServiceName": "OnPremMySqlLinkedService",
            "typeProperties": {},
            "availability": {
                "frequency": "Hour",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "external": true,
            "policy": {
                "externalData": {
                    "retryInterval": "00:01:00",
                    "retryTimeout": "01:00:00",
                    "maximumRetry": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

More details about how to create pipeline for Azure data factory, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud#create-pipeline)

More about the whole tutorial to move data from on-premise MySQL to Azure Data Factory,refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud).

Comment: Tried this. Still getting same error. And i am getting error in 10-15 minutes of pipeline execution.

Comment: @RuchitRami , You can go to Diagram  to view the data factory and double-click EmpOnPremSQLTable to  monitor pipeline. click see more to see what happened on your pipeline. If you see any error massage, please post here to let us know.

Comment: @RuchitRami , You can post your scripts of your pipeline  with updating your question if you don't mind.

Comment: I had included the error i found in the question. Have added more description for the script i am using.

Comment: @RuchitRami, What I mean is posting your  JSON  in the right pane of pipeline . So that I can see what your script is. Did you refer to the official document which I post  to configure this ?.

Comment: Posted complete error message. I had followed the exact JSON pattern mentioned by the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154866/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-ruchit-rami).